# terminate called recursively

Tags: c++, linux, exception

As far as I know, `terminate()` is called when there is some problem with exception handling(usually it's just not caught).
What I got is just one error line `terminate called recursively`.

After googling for some time I found a lot of examples of

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of ... terminate called recursively
```

But it's not my case. As I don't have this hint about the exception type, I'm wondering what does this `terminate called recursively` mean by itself.

Sorry I can't provide the code, so any guess will be helpful.
I'm compiling with g++ 4.5.2 under Ubuntu 11.04.

Thanks a lot,
Alex.

Comment: Without code we couldn't say anything. May be you have terminate handler, that writes "terminate called recursively".

Comment: Thanks @ForEveR. No, I'm not using set_terminate.

Comment: Try to debug, use gdb and core.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Could be that some code throws an exception you don't catch, which means `terminate` will be called. Terminating the program means that object destructors might be called, and if there is an exception in one of them then `terminate` will be called "recursively".

Comment: Still didn't find the problem, but sounds reasonable. Thanks!

Comment: This is not the answer.  When a destructor throws an exception during the stack unroll of anther exception, then the process will terminate immediately.  Try it and see.

Comment: "Terminating the program means that object destructors might be called" - They really shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

I have encounter this question, it's maybe the `error` of your function in `thread pool` or `thread`.

Let's recur the `terminate called recursively` `exception`.

I am writing a thread pool with `c++11`, here is my code:

```
// blocking queue
template<typename T>
class SafeQueue{ 
    public:
        bool pop(T& value){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            if(queue_.empty())
                return false;

            value = queue_.front();
            queue_.pop_front();
            return true;
        }

        void push(T&& value){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            queue_.push_back(std::move(value));
        }

        bool empty(){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
            return queue_.empty();
        }

    private:
        std::mutex mtx_;
        std::list<T> queue_;
};

typedef std::function<void()> Task;
typedef SafeQueue<Task> Tasks;

class ThreadPool{
    public:
        ThreadPool(uint32_t nums=5, bool start=false);
        ~ThreadPool();

        void start();
        void addTask(Task&& task);
        void join();
        void exit();
        size_t getThreadNum(){return threadNums_;}

    private:
        Tasks tasks_;

        std::vector<std::thread> threads_;
        size_t threadNums_;
        bool stop_;
};

ThreadPool::ThreadPool(uint32_t nums, bool start):
  threadNums_(nums), stop_(false)
{
    if(start)
        this->start();
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool(){
    stop_ = true;
}

void ThreadPool::start(){
    auto lb_thread_fun = [this](){
        while (!stop_){
            Task task;
            tasks_.pop(task);
            // error from here, task maybe empty.
            task();
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < threadNums_; ++i) {
        threads_.push_back(std::thread(lb_thread_fun));
    }
}

void ThreadPool::addTask(Task&& task){
    tasks_.push(std::move(task));
}

void ThreadPool::join(){
    for (auto& th:threads_) {
        th.join();
    }
}

void ThreadPool::exit(){
    stop_ = true;
}
```

**Test code as below:**

```
#include "my_threadpool.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

auto lb_dummy_dw = [](const std::string& url){
    cout<<"start downloading: "<<url<<endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    cout<<"downloading success !!!!"<<url<<endl;
};

auto lb_dummy_sql = [](int id, const std::string& name){
    cout<<"start select from db, id:" << id << ", name: "<<name<<endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    cout<<"select db success !!!!"<<endl;
};

void test_thread_pool(){
    cout<<"create thread pool with 5 thread"<<endl;
    xy::ThreadPool tp(5);

    cout<<"add 3 * 2 task to thread pool"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        tp.addTask(std::bind(lb_dummy_dw, "ww.xxx.com"));
        tp.addTask(std::bind(lb_dummy_sql, i, "xy" + std::to_string(i)));
    }

    cout<<"start thread pool"<<endl;
    tp.start();
    tp.join();
}

int main(){
    test_thread_pool();
    return 0;
}
```

**When you run the above code, you may get the below output:**

```
create thread pool with 5 thread
add 3 * 2 task to thread pool
start thread pool
start downloading: ww.xxx.com
start select from db, id:0, name: xy0
start downloading: ww.xxx.com
start select from db, id:1, name: xy1
start downloading: ww.xxx.com
downloading success !!!!ww.xxx.com
start select from db, id:2, name: xy2
downloading success !!!!ww.xxx.com
downloading success !!!!ww.xxx.com
terminate called recursively
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'
  what():
```

**You can see, it got `terminate called recursively` exception.** Because, in the function `start`, the variable `task` maybe empty,  so each thread in the `thread pool` throw `bad_function_call` exception.

```
void ThreadPool::start(){
    auto lb_thread_fun = [this](){
        while (!stop_){
            Task task;
            tasks_.pop(task);
            // error from here, task maybe empty.
            task();
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < threadNums_; ++i) {
        threads_.push_back(std::thread(lb_thread_fun));
    }
}
```

Task empty test code as below:

```
void test_task(){
    Task task;
    try{
        task();
    }catch (std::exception& e){
        cout<<"running task, with exception..."<<e.what()<<endl;
        return;
    }

    cout<<"ending task, without error"<<endl;
}
```

Output as below:

```
running task, with exception...bad_function_call
```