# c++ multithreading : terminate called recursively

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm pretty new to C++, and already involved in a rather complex project. The program is supposed to download a web site to be used offline. So to make it very simple what I've got is a "download manager" thread, creating as many "page downloader" threads as there as pages to download. In the same way, there also is an analysing thread tree. Here is the simplified code of the download manager :

```
void DlPage::manageDownload(){
    bool end=false;
    unique_lock<mutex> dlLck(dlMtx); // dlMtx is part of the shared data
    vector<thread*> downloads;

    cerr << "Download manager : entering" << endl;
    try{
        dlLck.lock();
    }catch (int e){
        cerr << "Download Manager : unique_lock thrown exception: " << e << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cerr << "Download manager : mutex locked" << endl;

    while(!end){
        // wait for a new page to be available for dl
        cerr << "Download manager : downloading page " << pageId << endl;
        // preparing data structures for download
        downloads.push_back(new thread(pageDownload, /*args*/));
        end=/*end condition*/;
    }

    dlLck.unlock();
    cerr << "Download manager : mutex unlocked" << endl;

    for(i=0;i<downloads.size();i++){
        downloads[i]->join();
        delete downloads[i];
    }
    dbgStream() << "Download manager : exiting" << endl;
}
```

And as output, I simply get :

```
Download manager : entering
Analyse manager : entering // Analyse manager has the exact same structure as download.
Main : Program launched // First page is added to the shared data and both managers are warned

terminate called recursively // what I don't understand
Aborted
```

At this point there is the main, and its 2 "manager" threads, created successfully as the output confirms it. And then, locking the mutex, even though any exception should be caught, crashes everything. And what's more, delivers an error message that should not appear in these circumstances. For what I understood, you'd get this message if the program can't destroy every object upon exiting a function.

Thank you for your help,

Jglukn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [terminate called recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347981/terminate-called-recursively)

Comment: also, consider using a tread pool or some mechanics to limit the amount of threads you are going to create. If "pages to download" is a big number you might end up having serious contention / context swictch issues resulting in really poor performance of your code.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Titles are rather similar, but I looked up this question before and the answer wasn't appropriate to my situation (or maybe not detailed enough and I'm too noob). Also he couldn't provide the code so the answer was only a guess.

Comment: @sergico Such a mechanism is implemented, just not showed here as I didn't consider it relevant. The program has to take as parameter the max number of threads anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This locks the mutex:

```
unique_lock<mutex> dlLck(dlMtx);
```

This tries to lock the mutex again, in the same thread, which throws an exception because the mutex is already locked:

```
try{
    dlLck.lock();
}catch (int e){
    cerr << "Download Manager : unique_lock thrown exception: " << e << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

The `catch` clause doesn't catch the right exception type, so the exception propagates to the caller, with results that can't be determined from the code here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I say I'm rather new to C++ so I was kind of expecting this sort of stupid detail to be the cause, but I've been on this bug for 10h and couldn't get my hand on it